# Visual Studio 2017 MVC Scaffolding - Add Custom Directory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I'm trying to customize the MvcControllerWithContextScaffolder (.NET Core 1.1.1), to adhere to the Repository-pattern and I've been succesful in doing so, by placing the Repository-class/interface within the controller-file itself.

However, I would like the repository class and interface to end up in their own respective directories within the solution. How do i achieve this? 
The scaffolder can be seen here:
[Repository Pattern Scaffolder](https://github.com/jepperaskdk/RepositoryPatternControllerScaffolding/blob/master/RepositoryScaffolding/Templates/ControllerGenerator/MvcControllerWithContext.cshtml)
A test-controller produced can be seen here: [TestsController.cs](https://github.com/jepperaskdk/RepositoryPatternControllerScaffolding/blob/master/RepositoryScaffolding/Controllers/TestsController.cs).

Update: I've done some digging, and believe the files are generated by this class: https://github.com/aspnet/Scaffolding/blob/dev/src/VS.Web.CG.Mvc/Controller/ControllerWithContextGenerator.cs